# This is my code for recognition of faces. I am getting the following error. i am using dlib shape predictor

Tags: python, opencv

```
align = openface.AlignDlib(dlibFacePredictor) subject=input("Enter Subject:") a=['BI','SIC','PGIS','SQA','ITSM'] path = 'C:/Users/ACER/Desktop/PROJECT ALL RESOURCE/Implementation/PYTHON FILES/images/' if subject in a: print("Success") wbook = load_workbook(filename = "C:/Users/ACER/Desktop/PROJECT ALL RESOURCE/Implementation/PYTHON FILES/Attendance/"+subject+".xlsx") sheet = wbook.get_sheet_by_name('TYBSCIT'+subject) else: print("Invalid")

def getDateColumns(): for i in range(1, len(sheet.rows[0]) + 1): cols = get_column_letter(i) if sheet.cell('%s%s'% (col,'1')).value == currentDate: return cols def getProfileId(Ids): connect = sqlite3.connect("C:/Users/ACER/Desktop/PROJECT ALL RESOURCE/Implementation/PYTHON FILES/sqlite3/Studentdb.db") cmd = "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE ID=" + str(Ids) cursor = connect.execute(cmd) profile = None for row in cursor: profile = row connect.close() return profile

attend = [0 for i in range(60)] rec = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create() # Local Binary Patterns Histograms rec.read('C:/Users/ACER/Desktop/PROJECT ALL RESOURCE/Implementation/PYTHON FILES/Training/trainingData.yml') # loading the trained data picNumber = 2 image= cv2.imread('C:/Users/ACER/Desktop/PROJECT ALL RESOURCE/Implementation/PYTHON FILES/images/'+subject+currentDate+'.jpg') font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX # the font of text on face recognition gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # conveting the camera input into GrayScale dets = detector(image, 1) totalConf = 0.0 faceRec = 0 for i, d in enumerate(dets): image2 = image[d.top():d.bottom(), d.left():d.right()] rgbImg = cv2.cvtColor(image2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) bb = align.getLargestFaceBoundingBox(rgbImg) alignedFace = align.align(96, rgbImg, bb=None, landmarkIndices=openface.AlignDlib.OUTER_EYES_AND_NOSE) alignedFace= cv2.cvtColor(alignedFace, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # conveting the camera input into GrayScale Ids, conf = rec.predict(alignFace) # Comparing from the trained data

Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\PROJECT ALL RESOURCE\Implementation\PYTHON FILES\facerecognition.py", line 60, in <module> Ids, conf = rec.predict(alignFace) # Comparing from the trained data NameError: name 'alignFace' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

As the TraceBack states, `alignFace` is not defined. You have made a typo of your previously-defined `alignedFace` - use this instead.